# Custom Post Type - Support "author" only for admins

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I would like to set up a **Custom Post Type** which supports the author feature only for admins.

Other user roles may as well create, see and edit their own posts, but the admins should be able to switch a post's author.

So far I managed to display only their own posts to non-admins thanks to the [pre_get_posts filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/).

And this is how I define the CPT. What can I do now to restrict the supports author only to admin users?

```
// CPT
function prefix_setup_cpt(){
register_post_type('whatever',
    array(
    'labels'        => array(
                      'name'           => 'Whatever',
                      'singular_name'  => 'Whatever'
                      ),
    'supports'      => array(
                      'title',
                      'editor',
                      'author'  // <--- This enables author feature
                      )
....
```

I am not seeking for a coded answer to copy/paste, but for hints about hooks and other WordPress facts that help me achieve the desired functionality.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: So you want that array to contain `"author"`, but only when the user has the admin role?

Comment: @TomJNowell How did I not see it that way? Thanks a lot for your help sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to *TomJNowell*'s help, this would be a possible working solution:

```
$supports = array(
    'title',
    'editor'
);
if(current_user_can('delete_plugins')){
    $supports[] = 'author';
}
register_post_type('whatever',
    array(
    'labels'        => array(
                      'name'           => 'Whatever',
                      'singular_name'  => 'Whatever'
                      ),
    'supports'      => $supports,
....
```